# How do I implement basic authentication in WebDAV using golang?

Tags: go, webdav

I want to implement a WebDAV server with basic authentication using golang.  Can some give me some pointers regarding this? TIA

Comment: WebDAV is an extension of HTTP by Microsoft, it add new verbs like LOCK, UNLOCK, so you should start first by either find a HTTP web server that handle this for you and allow you to add new verbs or developer yourself an HTTP Server

Comment: WebDAV is not an extension by microsoft. It's a web standard supported by many different vendors.

Answer (score 0):

The best pointer for anyone to get started is the specification:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918

Basic authentication is defined in RFC7617

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617